# CISCO SNMP map port identifier to physical port

Tags: cisco, snmp, fibre-channel

Given the identifier ([the id from fcsPortPhyPortNum](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=fcsPortPhyPortNum&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true)) and/or WWN of a FC switch port, how can I determine the physical location of the port on the switch (i.e., module 2/port 5 or fc2/5) via SNMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you walk the [CISCO-FE-FC-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2&mibName=CISCO-FC-FE-MIB) ?

It seems to cover the extended FC specifics that IF-MIB is missing.

Correlating this and IF-MIB ought to do the trick.

Comment: just answered myself.  it seems the port id in CISCO-FCS-MIB corresponds directly to the index in IF-MIB, which gives me the info i need.  i'll give you the credit though :)

Answer (score 1):

This information is in the [ifTable](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ifTable&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true).  The [ifIndex](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ifIndex&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) corresponds to [the id from fcsPortPhyPortNum](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=fcsPortPhyPortNum&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true).